# How can freeglut probe whether or not an X11 server is available?

Tags: c++, opengl, freeglut

I have a program which can display data graphically using `freeglut`, which is nice but not essential. I use `putty` a lot to edit and compile my program on a `debian` server at home but when I try to run the binary from within `putty` I get this message:

> freeglut (./a.out): failed to open display ''

Now I know that with a bit of fiddling about I could get cygwin to somehow tunnel the X server using `ssh -X`, but what I'd like is to simply detect if freeglut can render to the screen, and if it can't, simply to not bother.

How can I do this? I tried running a backtrace on my program in `gdb` but there's no stack, so I don't know if there's an exception or return value I can catch.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? You could use Xlib manually to try to get a connection to the X server, and react accordingly if that fails. But you should be aware that freeglut and the GL will need an X server to work.

Comment: @derhass, I'm basically trying to check whether an X server exists. If it does, I'll run `glutInit()`, etc. If it doesn't, I'll just write to the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`glutInit()`](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/glut/spec3/node10.html):

> glutInit will initialize the GLUT library and negotiate a session with the window system. **During this process, glutInit may cause the termination of the GLUT program with an error message to the user if GLUT cannot be properly initialized. Examples of this situation include the failure to connect to the window system**, the lack of window system support for OpenGL, and invalid command line options.

So, no, you can't really handle a missing X server with GLUT.  Short of some nasty hacks like a parent watchdog process or hooking `exit()` somehow.

Comment: Ah. I had read that earlier but took it to mean "*you can't detect a missing X server using glutInit()*", ie. not precluding the possibility of such a mechanism existing elsewhere...